# Pull to Refresh adds same data already have

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, pull-to-refresh

I am having a hard time finishing the implementation of Pull to Refresh.

When I **Pull to Refresh, it just adds the same data I already have.**  So I'll just get the same data, multiplied by 2.

`viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: "handleRefresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Play", predicate: predicate)
    publicData.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { results, error in
        if error == nil { // There is no error
            for play in results! {
                let newPlay = Play()

                newPlay.color = play["Color"] as! String

                self.objects.append(newPlay)

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
            }
        }
        else {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

`handleRefresh`:

```
func handleRefresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {

    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Play", predicate: predicate)
    publicData.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { results, error in
        if error == nil { // There is no error
            for play in results! {
                let newPlay = Play()

                newPlay.color = play["Color"] as! String

                self.objects.append(newPlay)

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
            })
            }
        }
        else {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

I started thinking that maybe it was that I needed to remove all of the `objects` before I appended the new ones, but somehow that didn't work adding this line `self.objects.removeAll()` before `self.objects.append(newPlay)` in `handleRefresh` function.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `self.objects.removeAll()` before the for loop and it should work properly.
By putting it in the for loop, you empty your datasource every iteration.

Comment: Perfect.  Will accept answer in 2 minutes when it lets me.

Comment: Also put your dispatch_async block after the for loop. It gets called for nothing for each item you have.